# Performance question about string slicing in Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, set, slice

I am learning some python and in the process of it I'm doing some simple katas from codewars. 
I run into https://www.codewars.com/kata/scramblies problem.

My solution went as follows:

```
def scramble(s1,s2):
    result = True
    for character in s2:
        if character not in s1:
            return False
        i = s1.index(character)
        s1 = s1[0:i] + s1[i+1:]
    return result
```

While it was correct result, it wasn't fast enough. My solution timed out after 12000 ms.
I looked at the solutions presented by others and one involved making a set.

```
  def scramble(s1,s2):
     for letter in set(s2):
        if s1.count(letter) < s2.count(letter):
          return False
     return True
```

Why is my solution so much slower than the other one? It doesn't look like it should be unless I am misunderstanding something efficiency of slicing strings. Is my approach to solving this problem flawed or not pythonic?

Comment: set is very fast.

Comment: I disassembled both functions with dis, yours is 71 commands. and the correct one is only

Comment: The number of bytecode instructions has little bearing on the algorithm's efficiency, and the set here isn't being used for anything other than iteration. Iterating over a set isn't faster than iterating over a sequence; the benefit comes from when the set is smaller than the sequence because there are many duplicate elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of online programming challenge with a limit on your program's running time, the test inputs will include some quite large examples, and the time limit is usually set so that you don't have to squeeze every last millisecond of performance out of your code, but you do have to write an algorithm of a low enough [computational complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity). To answer why your algorithm times out, we can analyse it to find its computational complexity using [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

First we can label each individual statement with its complexity, where `n` is the length of `s1` and `m` is the length of `s2`:

```py
def scramble(s1,s2):
    result = True                  # O(1)
    for character in s2:           # loop runs O(m) times
        if character not in s1:        # O(n) to search characters in s1
            return False               # O(1)
        i = s1.index(character)        # O(n) to search characters in s1
        s1 = s1[0:i] + s1[i+1:]        # O(n) to build a new string
    return result                  # O(1)
```

Then the total complexity is O(1 + m*(n + 1 + n + n) + 1) or more simply, O(m*n). This is not efficient for this problem.

---

The key to why the alternate algorithm is faster lies in the fact that `set(s2)` contains only the distinct characters from the string `s2`. This is important because the alphabet that these strings are formed from has a constant, limited size; presumably 26 for the lowercase letters. Given this, the outer loop of the alternate algorithm actually runs at most 26 times:

```py
def scramble(s1,s2):
    for letter in set(s2):                      # O(m) to build a set 
                                                # loop runs O(1) times
        if s1.count(letter) < s2.count(letter):     # O(n) + O(m) to count
                                                    # chars from s1 and s2
            return False                            # O(1)
    return True                                 # O(1)
```

This means the alternate algorithm's complexity is O(m + 1*(n + m + 1) + 1) or more simply O(m + n), meaning it is asymptotically more efficient than your algorithm.

Comment: Thank you very much for this response. I know about big O notation but I didn't know that my string manipulations were O(n). Very detailed answer and exactly what I was looking for:)

Comment: The string manipulations are O(n) because strings are immutable, so they can't be changed in-place. Building a new string in memory requires allocating and copying as many characters as the length of the string, which is O(n) in this case. However, note that because the other two things you're doing within the loop are also O(n), faster string operations wouldn't reduce the asymptotic complexity of your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `set` is fast and very good at its job. For things like `in`, `set` is faster than `list`.

Second of all, your solution is doing *way* more work than the correct solution. Note how the second solution never modifies `s1` or `s2`, whereas your solution both takes *two slices* of `s1` and then reassigns `s1`. This, along with calling `.index()`. Slicing isn't the fastest operation, mainly because memory has to be allocated and data has to be copied. `.remove()` would probably be faster than the combination of `.index()` and slicing that you're doing.

The underlying message here is if the task can be done in fewer operations, it's obviously going to execute more quickly. Slicing is also more expensive than most other methods because *allocating space and copying memory* is a more expensive operation than the computational methods like `.count()` that the correct solution uses.

Comment: In the alternative solution, the set isn't being used for `in` or any other operation which is naturally faster on a set. The only thing the set is used for is to iterate over it. However, for this particular problem it's only necessary to iterate over *distinct* characters from the string `s2`, so using a set means each distinct character is only checked once, which is more efficient than checking each character as many times as it appears.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Had no idea slicing is that expensive